# Cross-domain request sometimes is empty

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

Take a look at [this demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/LNccW/4/)

Here you can see a simplified version of my code that tries to make an ajax request to some url (to get it's information).

There is also a JS code that **makes possible cross-domain requests**.

The problem is that sometimes the request returns no information, and sometimes it works like a charm.

For example, in jsfiddle link above you can see that there I have 2 variables:

```
var testurl = "http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/its-official-ubuntu-gnome-remix-joins-the-ubuntu-family";
var testurl2 = "http://habrahabr.ru/post/172755/";
```

If you edit the code and set URL variable equals **testurl** - the results of the ajax call will not be empty (it can be seen clearly, and in console). But if you set URL variable to **testurl2** - the request will be empty.

Why so? Is there a workaround?

Comment: For me, the server responded `jQuery1910002007946604862809_1363337650054({"query":{"count":"0","created":"2013-03-15T08:54:29Z","lang":"en-US"},"results":[]});` for testurl2. *Chrome 25 / Mac 10.7*

Comment: but why no page content displayed?